# Firebug showing infinite recursion for constructor

Tags: javascript, firebug

I wanted to dig in into the language specific construct "prototype" of javascript.
And here is my learning purpose code:

```
var f = function() {};
f.ext = 1;
f.prototype.pext = 2;
```

When i debug this code now with firebug, i get the following:
[image]

Where does this infinite nesting come from?
Let's begin from top (OK=unterstood):

f                   (OK) 
 - ext              (OK) 
 - prototype        (OK) 
   - pext           (OK) 
     - constructor  (I'm stuck at this point)

Whose constructor is that? And why do we have this infinte nesting?

Comment: I think it's because the prototype of an anonymous function is an anonymous function. Since you're setting a property on function's prototype it sets that property on function's prototype which is setting a property on function's prototype...etc. Not sure though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its simply because `f === f.prototype.constructor`, those are the same and Firebug shows them as circular references.

The same as:

```
var a = {},
    b = a;
a.b = b;
```

You will see infinite references here too.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this

```
Foo = function () {
    // Do something
};
```

then you will have this

```
Foo.prototype.constructor == Foo
```

as `Foo` is the constructor for `Foo`:

```
var foo = new Foo(); // <-- Foo is the constructor.
```

I recommend this reading: http://beej.us/blog/data/javascript-prototypes-inheritance/